# Python messing vim when spawning

Tags: python, vim, subprocess

I'm trying to run a program from python and print the output based on its exit status.  The code below is outputting directly to my vim screen (messing it) instead of opening a shell with the output.

[image]

```
python << EOF
import subprocess
import vim

cmd = "BAD_COMMAND"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
retcode = p.poll()
if retcode > 0:
    output_of_error = p.communicate()[0]
    vim.command("!echo show errors here")

EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to redirect your subprocess to a pipe:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

`communicate()` will then return a 2-tuple containing the contents of `stdout` and `stderr` of the process.